# How to listen to polymer-gesture events imperatively

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

I built a behavior to make Polymer elements draggable, but when I add the event listener imperatively it isn't called.

```
abstract class DraggableBehavior implements PolymerBase, dom.Element {
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    this.on['track'].listen(_dragHandler);
  }

  void _dragHandler(dom.CustomEvent event, [_]) {
    print(event.type);
  }
}
```

As soon as I add `on-track="someOtherTrackHandler"` (note the different name of the event handler) `dragHandler` is called just fine.

It seems Polymer enables polymer-gesture events only when event handlers are added imperatively.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Using `listen` from the Polymer API (`PolymerBase`) instead works

```
void attached() {
  super.attached();
  listen(this, 'track', 'dragHandler');
}

@reflectable
void dragHandler(dom.CustomEvent event, [_]) {
  print(event.type);
}
```